# Native Java Corba ORBD doesn't work

Tags: corba

I'm trying to start orbd on Windows XP 32, JDK 1.6, Java Client VM.

I've tried: start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050, but orbd doesn't start.
I saw a warning message: 
BAD_PARAM could not load class standard_init

followed by:
GRAVE (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create listener thread on the specified port: 1049

I'm sure nothing uses port 1050, or 1049 either (netstat confirms it), moreover I get the same error no matter which port I use.

I don't know what to do, it looked very simple to start orbd, non preliminary actrion, simply giving the command start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050, but it doesn't work.
Am I forgetting any action ? Do I need JavaEE instead of JavaSE ?

any help would be really appreciated

bye
William

Comment: If you write a small program in some language of your choice that tries to listen to those ports, does it still not work? If it doesn't, the problem is not in the ORB implementation but in your system. Perhaps a very picky firewall? Or you trying to start something in daemon mode without being administrator?

Comment: I used a Java socket application on those ports without any trouble.

Comment: But every port I use, I obtain the same errors.

Comment: I used a Java socket application on those ports without any trouble. Every port I use, I obtain the same errorsYesterday I tried a Linux SUSE server and obtained the same errors. I'm the administrator. I wonder if anybody has ever seen ORBD working, perhaps it needs Java EE instead of Java SE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`orbd` will bind to port `1049` regardless of `-ORBInitialPort` option.

Please check whether or not another `orbd` instance or another process is already running and bound to that port. (e.g., use `netstat`)

You have to add the `-port` option to change the so-called activation port of `1049`

E.g. `orbd -ORBInitialPort 2000 -port 1999`

Hint: Make sure that you don't have a forgotten `orb.properties` file in your home directory

Comment: Unfortunately the outcome is always the same, no matter which port I use, even if I try 1999 or 19999... imho there are two sole possibilities: ORBD doesn't work under normal conditions (without some trick not documented), or there's something in my machines that causes the ORBD's failure (everything else is working fine, though)

Comment: if you use my commandline example, you're getting an error with port 1049?

Comment: I tried your commandline, but the outcome is always the same,  ClassNotFoundException: standard_init.

Comment: Please post your complete call to orbd if its not only ´orbd -ORBInitialPort 2000 -port 1999´. Please also have a look at orb.properties file in your home directory.

Comment: I've found an old jacorb orb.properties in my home dir, I've completely forgotten about it. So, I renamed it and now orbd works !!! Thank you a lot, really!